# ¿Cómo resolver este problema?

Tags: sql, trigger

Suponiendo creada la siguiente tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE PAISES_SUPERPOBLADOS AS
SELECT cod_pais, nombre, num_hab, extension, num_hab/extension AS densidad
FROM pais
WHERE num_hab > 90000000;
```

Se desea crear un disparador en PL/SQL llamado `TRG_SUPERPOBLACION`, que se
active a nivel de registro, tras cada operación DML sobre la tabla PAIS, con el
siguiente comportamiento:

a) Si se realizó una inserción en la tabla PAIS, deberá insertar un registro idéntico
en la tabla `PAISES_SUPERPOBLADOS` si y sólo si la población del país insertado
supere los 90 millones de habitantes.

b) Si el país ya existiese en la tabla `PAISES_SUPERPOBLADOS`, levantaría una
excepción indicando el mensaje de error.

Comment: Has intentado resolver esa tarea? Podrías incluir lo que has tratado de hacer por ti mismo

Comment: el problema que tengo es que no consigo hacer el insertar un registro idéntico .Losiento por no subir lo que he hecho pero me parecía tan escaso que era ridículo subirlo

Comment: Como dato adicional (y asumiendo que esto es una tarea y no un problema del mundo real) es importante recalcar que no se deben guardar filas idénticas en múltiples tablas. Lo mejor es solo hacer únicamente una copia de la llave primaria de la tabla principal. O en el mejor de los casos, una vista puede ser suficiente con los índices correctos.